# Change Style of TextSelection on WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, .net-6.0

I have a WPF RichTextBox and i'm trying to do is change the style:
FontFamily, FontSize, FontWeight, Color and some more.

I can change some of this values on the selected Text,
but i can't find a TextDecorationProperty

CodeExample:

```
TextSelection textRange = richTextBoxWpf.Selection;                
if (btBold.IsChecked ?? false)
{
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
btBold.IsChecked = true;
}
else
{
btBold.IsChecked = false;
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
}
```

My code fails on set the Property:

```
var pens = new System.Windows.Media.Pen(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, 1);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextDecoration.PenProperty, pens);
```

Fail Error-Message: "Die Pen-Eigenschaft ist für die Textformatierung nicht gültig."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after a long search I found the Solution myself:

It in the Documents.Inline class:

```
TextSelection textRange = richTextBoxWpf.Selection;

textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
```